# Python Fuzzy matching strings in list performance

Tags: python, duplicates, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I'm checking if there are similar results (fuzzy match) in 4 same dataframe columns, and I have the following code, as an example. When I apply it to the real 40.000 rows x 4 columns dataset, keeps running in eternum. The issue is that the code is too slow. For example, if I limite the dataset to 10 users, it takes 8 minutes to compute, while for 20, 19 minutes. Is there anything I am missing? I do not know why this take that long. I expect to have all results, maximum in 2 hours or less. Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
dataframecolumn = ["apple","tb"]
compare = ["adfad","apple","asple","tab"]
Ratios = [process.extract(x,compare) for x in dataframecolumn]
result = list()
for ratio in Ratios:
    for match in ratio:
        if match[1] != 100:
            result.append(match)
            break
print (result)
```

Output:
[('asple', 80), ('tab', 80)]

Comment: try to implement Levenshtein Distance by your own and see the difference between execution times. maybe the library that you're using has problems with time efficiency

Comment: @CristianIacob I am using fuzzywuzzy

Comment: I've solved this problem in past but would need more info here. Are you looking for string similarity using ratio or partial ratio or both ? Are you using extract function just to speed up the process ?

Comment: @Atendra using ratio (not partial), and I amb using the extract function to speed it up, yes. As far as I can achieve the expected result, I am open to any new code.

Comment: I hope below answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Major speed improvements come by writing vectorized operations and avoiding loops

## Importing necessary package

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

## Creating dataframe from first list

```
dataframecolumn = pd.DataFrame(["apple","tb"])
dataframecolumn.columns = ['Match']
```

## Creating dataframe from second list

```
compare = pd.DataFrame(["adfad","apple","asple","tab"])
compare.columns = ['compare']
```

## Merge - Cartesian product by introducing key(self join)

```
dataframecolumn['Key'] = 1
compare['Key'] = 1
combined_dataframe = dataframecolumn.merge(compare,on="Key",how="left")
combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe[~(combined_dataframe.Match==combined_dataframe.compare)]
```

## Vectorization

```
def partial_match(x,y):
    return(fuzz.ratio(x,y))
partial_match_vector = np.vectorize(partial_match)
```

## Using vectorization and getting desired result by putting threshold on score

```
combined_dataframe['score']=partial_match_vector(combined_dataframe['Match'],combined_dataframe['compare'])
combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe[combined_dataframe.score>=80]
```

## Results

```
+--------+-----+--------+------+
| Match  | Key | compare | score
+--------+-----+--------+------+
| apple  | 1   |   asple |    80
|  tb    | 1   |   tab   |    80
+--------+-----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Executing your script, the result is different from what you give. It returns    ```Match  Key compare  score
1  apple    1   apple    100```

Comment: forgot to include negation. Corrected it now. try and let me know. Its now giving same output.

Comment: This doesn't work with very large datasets. I have 50,000 strings in a column to compare to another column of 400,000 strings. There is a `Memoryerror` when merging these with your code `Merge - Cartesian product by introducing key(self join)`

Comment: @SCool since data is relatively moderate , number of combinations would increase significantly. Can you reduce these combinations through some filter or logic, Do you really need to match all 50 K strings with 4 Lac Strings ? If yes, you would need more RAM.

Comment: Very useful thanks! Just to add I had to try different fuzzy methods with my data, `token_set_ratio` worked best.
https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-for-fuzzy-string-matching-with-python-6632b7824c49