# Fast way to look up String Similarity against a large list of strings?

Tags: python, string, nlp, similarity

My aim is to identify the top 10 most similar strings in a large list of strings, given an input string. This is for a web-based API so I would need a very fast response time (<100ms is ideal).

I am operating on Python but can be flexible if there is a better way to achieve this (be it through Bash scripts or another language). I have tried a variety of approaches so far, including [difflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802137/how-to-use-sequencematcher-to-find-similarity-between-two-strings) and [fuzzywuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040817/python-fuzzy-matching-strings-in-list-performance/56165274#56165274) but the results returned have either been too slow or not returning ideal results.

In the case of my most recent experiment, the solution using fuzzywuzzy returns an un-ideal result set.

An input of "coupons" returns:

```
                     Query         Stem  Key compare  score
34046              copson       copson    1  coupon     83
35011           couponcom    couponcom    1  coupon     80
61206             groupon      groupon    1  coupon     77
5834          able coupon   abl coupon    1  coupon     75
124231        rjr coupons   rjr coupon    1  coupon     75
35026          couponscom   couponscom    1  coupon     75
34991             couples        coupl    1  coupon     73
34993   couples dominated  coupl domin    1  coupon     71
11236        arbys coupon  arbi coupon    1  coupon     71
```

While there are related keywords in the result set,non-related keywords ("couples")I know that better results the exist in the large corpus of strings are being overlooked due to the fact they have a larger edit distance between it and the original query. E.g. "birthday coupon", "supermarket coupons"

Is there an approach that does something like n-gram matching to ensure a more relevant similarity? Speed is the high priority here, I deal with issues such as mis-spellings and stemming ahead of time.

Comment: If you're looking for n-gram matching, have you tested if the performance of the [ngram module](https://pythonhosted.org/ngram/ngram.html#ngram.NGram.search) is acceptable for you? If using n-grams is not a requirement, how do you define "relevant similarity"?

Answer (score 0):

String similarity is a broad topic in NLP so it is important to decide on the metric. `fuzzywuzzy` uses [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is appropriate to deal with misspellings but does not address semantic similarity in any way. From what you write this is what you are looking for so I suggest that you use Word2Vec model via `gensim` library.

For this I suggest you refer to answer to this question: [How to use word2vec to calculate the similarity distance by giving 2 words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979970/how-to-use-word2vec-to-calculate-the-similarity-distance-by-giving-2-words)