# Performance optimization when using two for loops for list comparison

Tags: python, string, list, loops, fuzzywuzzy

I am currently trying to compare each element of one list with every element of another list. This has a time complexity of N*N  which is a hindrance to the performance.

The loops are as follows:

```
#fin_textt is a list which contains strings

for i in (range(len(fin_textt))):
    for j in range(i+1,len(fin_textt)):
        if(fuzz.ratio(fin_textt[i],fin_textt[j])<90):
            continue
        else:
            dup.append((fin_textt[i],fin_textt[j]))#all reviews which are very similar and have a value 90 and above
```

The time taken to give an output when the above code is run on a 10k dataset is awfully large.
Please help me optimize this and boost the performance.

Comment: You can't do much without changing your requirements. Are there duplicates in those lists?

Comment: try to use multi thread

Comment: Yes, dup contains a list of duplicate reviews.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use multi thread in this case?

Comment: You could try  [Python Fuzzy matching strings in list performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040817/python-fuzzy-matching-strings-in-list-performance) whose answer by Atendra vectorized the computation.  There may be an may be CPU memory issue with 10k datasets.